# Mle on discrete distribution in table

Tags: maximum-likelihood, inference, discrete-data

Consider the probability distribution p(x; $\theta $ ), x=2, 3, 4, 5 and $\theta $   = 1/4, 1/2, 3/4.  A sample of size 1 is drawn from the population and it is found to be 3. Obtain the maximum likelihood estimate of $\theta $ .
\begin{array}{ l |c } x & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5  \\\ 
P( x, \hat{\theta} = 1/4)  & 0.25 & 0.25 & 0.25 & 0.25 \\\ 
P( x, \hat{\theta} = 1/2)  & 0.30 & 0.40 & 0.15 & 0.15 \\\ 
P( x, \hat{\theta} = 3/4)  & 0.10 & 0.30 & 0.45 & 0.15  \\ 
\end{array}

Now this is the question  , I have a major confusion here

Generally in such table  mle questions

we gind the liklihood function by multiplying their probability and

then taking  log ,

then to maximize the likelihood function we find the derivative of it ,

equate it to zero and then find  $\theta $ ,

but what shall I do here since $\theta$  is already given .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one goes to the very literal meaning of the term "maximum likelihood": Given that the sample was 3, which value of $\theta$ would maximize the likelihood function? The answer, according to the table, is $\hat{\theta}=\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Since sample number 3 is selected so we will select x =3

And in x=3 the maximum probability is 0.40 so the maximum likelihood estimator

$\hat \theta  $ will be 1/2
.